# How to implement keyboard function shortcut key on websites?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I want to use a keyboard function key in my  website. So how can I implement keyboard function shortcut key on my website. Thanks for everyone.......

Comment: for this you would use javascript.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "keyboard function shortcut key"? Do you want to create key keyboard shortcuts such as "Ctrl+N" or "Alt+N" on your website?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?259973-Detect-Fn-keys

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript:

```
// event.type should be keypress
function getChar(event) {
    if (event.which == null) {  // IE
        if (event.keyCode < 32) return null; // special character
            return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) 
    } 

    if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0) { // not IE
        if (event.which < 32) return null; // special character
            return String.fromCharCode(event.which); // other
    } 

    return null; // special character
}
```

For control keys use: event.shiftKey, event.ctrlKey, event.altKey or event.metaKey.

Comment: I want use a function key like ctrl,shift,F1,F2 etc in my website.........

Answer (score 1):

Good.If you dont know jquery,I would suggest you to learn javascript first.
There are keycodes for very key present on the keyboard.You just need to detect the keypress of which key is being pressed and add your game functionality in accordance with which key is being pressed.
[image: List of all buttons]

**InGeneral**-->

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == "any of the above key") {
        alert("some key pressed");
//your functionality goes here!!!
    }
};
```

**For what you want**-->

```
$('#someelement').bind('click', function(event){
   if(event.ctrlKey)
      alert('ctrl pressed');
   if(event.altKey)
      alert('alt pressed');
   if(event.shiftKey)
      alert('shift pressed');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using jQuery, then it can be a bit simpler.

To be able to capture compound keys, you have to first look for a keydown on control key and store the state. Then look for a keydown on regular key and check it against the stored state. Once there is a keyup, reset the control state.

Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
// Bind keyup to document to trap shortcut keys for various operations
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    IsCtrl = false;
    IsShift = false;
}).keydown(function (e) {

    // first capture Ctrl 
    if (e.which == 17) { IsCtrl = true; }

    // now capture Shift 
    if (e.which == 16) { IsShift = true; }

    switch (e.which) {

        // now capture S and if Ctrl is pressed                                                                                                                                                                                          
        case 83: 
            if (IsCtrl) { alert("Ctrl S pressed");  } 
            if (IsShift) { alert("Shift S pressed");  } 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            break;

        // capture F1                                                                                                                                                                                           
        case 112: alert("Heellllppp!"); e.preventDefault(); break;

        // capture ESC                                                                                                                                                                                           
        case 27: alert("Escape!"); e.preventDefault(); break;
    }
});
```

Where "`IsCtrl`" and "`IsShift`" are variables in global scope. The above code checks for control keys exclusively. If you want to check further combinations (inclusive), please change the part where to check for the control-key states. Function keys start from 112 (f1). You can get the other keycodes by referring to the chart posted by @MESSIAH.

Hope that helps.